# Как получить корректную дату из базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql

В базе данных `mysql` есть поле `date`. В записях базы данных дата выглядит как ***2015-01-15 23:58:58***. Мне нужно перевести ее миллисекунды и добавить миллисекунды, которые находятся в другой ячейке. Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
java.util.Date date = rs.getDate(DATE_COLUMN);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
long second = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long ms1 = rs.getInt(MSEC_COLUMN);
long time1 = second + ms1;
```

но не дата приходит в виде 2015-01-15 и поэтому я не учитываю минуты и секунды. Помогите пожалуйста, никак не могу разобраться.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133760/mysql-convert-datetime-to-unix-timestamp Возможно поможет.

Comment: Показывайте текст запроса, которым получаете данные. И укажите тип поля, в котором хранится дата-время в MySQL.

Comment: Возможно поможет `date = rs.getTimeStamp(DATE_COLUMN);`

Comment: да, помогло, спасибо)